# How to write a Sqoop Job using shell script

Tags: sqoop

My use case:

Day by day hourly tables gets created in mysql db. I need to move them everyday to HDFS using Sqoop and process the HDFS data using Impala.

How to write a shell script or job only to move the tables data that are newly created to HDFS(existing file system) periodically?

Say today is 3rd of Jan 2016, when I run my job today then 2nd Jan 2016 data should be moved from mysql to HDFS like wide everyday it should move the data of previous day.
Daily I need to run my Impala queries on this HDFS cluster and generate a report.
How to process this whole data using Impala and generate a report?

Answer (score 1):

Sqoop supports incremental import: http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_incremental_imports

`Sqoop-import` can use either a last-modified timestamp, or an always-increasing row ID to decide which rows to import. You need to provide a `--last-value` parameter. You could store the last value in between jobs, or maybe retrieve it from your Impala database before running the job.

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to get shell script that takes 2 arguments. 1 would be the name of the table and other would be hdfs path because those would be the only 2 factors that change in your scenarios. Below is sample script that you can put into .sh and run in bash.

```
    !/bin/bash 

    TABLENAME=${^^1} 
    HDFSPATH=${^^2} 
    NOW=$(date +"%m-%d-%Y-%H-%M-%S") 

    sqoop --import --connect jdbc:db2://mystsrem:60000/SCHEMA \
     --username username \
     --password-file password \
     --query "select * from ${TABLENAME} \$CONDITIONS" \
     -m 1 \
     --delete-target-dir \
     --target-dir ${HDFSPATH} \
     --fetch-size 30000 \
     --class-name ${TABLENAME} \
     --fields-terminated-by '\01' \
     --lines-terminated-by '\n' \
     --escaped-by '\' \
     --verbose &> logonly/${TABLENAME}_import_${NOW}.log
```

OPTIONAL:
if you need to import into hive table

--hive-drop-import-delims \
--hive-import \
--hive-overwrite \
--hive-table HiveSchema.${TABLENAME}

Comment: What does '\01' mean delimited with??

Comment: Sometimes its also referred to as Start of Header (SOH)

Comment: how does '\01' referred as SOH?? can you explain a bit please?

Comment: The name of the delimiter is SOH, Please see the link http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0001/index.htm